# Laravel Mix says 'build successful', but changes made in resources/app.js don't execute

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm seeing similar questions have been asked previously, but I seem to be having a unique problem with adding new code in my `resources/app.js` file. I have cleared my cache in chrome, I have disabled cache in devtools, restarted my computer, and I've even made changes to existing code in the same file, which DOES execute in the browser. In the offchance that it's the code, here is what I wrote:

```
const welcomeIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.welcome-card-icon');

for (let i = 0; i<welcomeIcon.length; i++){
    welcomeIcon[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
console.log('clicked!')}
    );
};
```

No errors thrown, plus the exact same code works in the dev console when copied and pasted. Please help!

Comment: Can you see this code inside the newly compiled JS file in `public/js/app.js`?

Comment: @James Yes I can

Comment: Is this code wrapped in some conditional statement or something? It is clearly getting compiled in. Or is the content it is targeting loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @James No, it's not. I only wrote this code to begin testing an event listener, which led me to discover that changes in my ```resources/app.js``` were not being rendered in the browser

Comment: Is the script tag that imports your app.js file at the bottom of your HTML body or is it at the top?